# Infinite loop to wait for the variable value to change, and check every 30 seconds in mongo shell

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop, mongo-shell

Writing a bash script where I connect to mongo-shell. I have the following output for `rs.status()`. I have to wait for one of the members to change the value of `stateStr` to `Secondary`. In the output below, you can see, right now it says `Not active`. I want to write an infinite loop which will iterate through the all the members, and check the `stateStr` every 30 seconds until the there is a `Secondary`.

```js
"members" : [
  { "stateStr" : "Not active" },
  { "stateStr" : "PRIMARY" },
  { "stateStr" : "ARBITER" }
],
```

Here's what I have so far:

```js
mongo --host ${other_host} ${ssl_mode} <<EOF
    while (true){
            for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
                    if (rs.status().members[i].stateStr == "SECONDARY") {
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }
    rs.status();
EOF
```

This however doesn't break out of the infinite loop. And I want to check every 30 seconds. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
mongo --host ${other_host} ${ssl_mode} << EOF
  while (rs.status().members.every(e => e.stateStr != "SECONDARY")) {
    sleep(1000);  
  }
  rs.status();
  EOF
```

Note that I also added a `sleep`, to avoid busy waiting.

---

Update 1:
If your mongo version is a little older, then you may not be able to use arrow functions and will need to spell it out like this:

```
  while (rs.status().members.every(function(e) { return e.stateStr != "SECONDARY"; })) {
```

Comment: That's actually really cool syntax that I didn't know of. how would I also look for "if stateStr=Primary && stateStr=Arbiter" for every member using same syntax. If found then exit out with print("Success"), else exit with print("Failure") ? This would be done after I've exited out of the while loop. Also, it prints out "null" for some reason even though it works, I tried using --quiet in the line where I'm connecting to mongo shell but that didn't help.

Comment: Done! I tried this: 
if (rs.status().members.every(function(e) { return e.stateStr = "ARBITER" && e.stateStr = "PRIMARY" })) {
                                print("All nodes are up and running");
                        }
but it failed

Comment: a) you are using = (assignment) when you should use == (comparison). b) how can it be arbiter and primary at the same time?

Comment: a) Yeah, I changed it to == b) there are 3 members, so basically i just want to make sure that one of them is arbiter and some other member is primary.